# React - scroll to bottom when there is a new message not fully working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my component,

```
const Chat = () => {
  // some code

  const bottomOfMessagesRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    bottomOfMessagesRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behaviour: 'smooth' });
  }, [message]);

  // some more code
  return (
    <>
      {/* some jsx */}

      <ul className={`${ChatStyles.messages} scrollStyling`}>
        {msgList.map((msg, idx) => {
          // even more jsx
          return (
            <>
              <li className={className}>{`${msg.username}: ${msg.message}`}</li>
            </>
          );
        })}

        <div ref={bottomOfMessagesRef}></div>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

here, im doing a "scrollIntoView" onto bottomOfMessagesRef/div before closing ul tag everytime there is a new message,

what actually happens is that i scrollIntoView'd onto the element *before* "bottomOfMessagesRef"

any thoughts?

Comment: Can't say for sure because this is not a minimal reproducible example but does your `useEffect` not need `msgList` as a dependency and not `messages`? I'd assume that your messages variable updates your msgList variable, and since the state hasn't updated yet the scroll function updates before it's meant to.

Comment: Sorry for that, but yea you were right, it was because i needed my dependency as msgList, not messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a variable called `messages` that you use to update the `msgList` variable.

This means that because the `useEffect` has `messages` as a dependency it will scroll before `msgList` updates. Remove `messages` as a dependency and add `msgList` instead and it should work.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    bottomOfMessagesRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behaviour: 'smooth' });
}, [msgList]);
```